# vite gitlab ci job be killed then exit with code 1?

Tags: gitlab-ci, vite

I'm so confused why this happen. every thing seem ok in my .gitlab-ci.yml, if I run `npm run build` locally it works correctly as below
[image]

Problem shows as below.
[image]

```js
image: node
cache:
  paths:
    - dist
    - node_modules
stages:
  - prepare
  - build
  - deploy

prepare:
  stage: prepare
  script:
    - npm ci --cache .npm --prefer-offline

build:
  stage: build
  needs: 
    - prepare
  script:
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  before_script:
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( yum update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_DEV"
    - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_DEV")
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
  script:
    - scp -r ./dist/ $CUSTOM_USERNAME@$CUSTOM_IP:/home/docker-nginx
```

**Note:**  the problem being build stage. I had tried to change the script of build like

```js
script:
  - echo 'whyyyyy'
```

then everything is ok.....why it killed my build stage at the end.

Answer (score 2):

If a gitlab job gets killed it probably ran out of memory. You should take a look at your gitlab server logs and check for any out of memory Errors.

Comment: no more anyother error, the only error was shown above..